# How much cargo does each type of ship typically carry?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

This question is unrelated to Kenway's Fleet, it only focuses on the actual free-roaming world.

In Assassin's Creed 4, the player can look at a ship through the spyglass, seeing useful information such as the cargo (the five types - Wood, Metal, Cloth, Rum and Sugar) it carries, as seen in the top right of the picture below.

[image: Image from http://cdn.cheatcc.com, showing the level 17 brig Proteus with 55 metal and 15 rum.]

**My question is, how much wood, metal, cloth, rum or sugar would you expect to find on each type of ship?**

Now, unfortunately the 'type' is also another question in itself. Does the cargo vary depending on:

- Whether the ship is a gunboat/schooner/brig/frigate/man o’ war?
- Whether the ship is British, Spanish, owned by pirates or is a Hunter?
- How high the level of a ship is?

It seems to be randomised, maybe there is a particular range the number of each type of cargo falls between?